# Can I mix cook and serve pudding with instant pudding after I've cooked the pudding

Tags: mixing, pudding

Can I add a box of instant pudding into my pan of cook and serve pudding when the cook is almost done, mix together and use?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the powder straight to the cooked pudding appears to be what you are asking, and seems **very likely to be problematic, though I have not tried it.** The instant pudding expects a certain amount of liquid, and the cooked pudding is probably too thick to behave as the makers of the instant pudding expect liquid to behave, so lumps and various unpleasantness would appear to be likely, without trying it.

Preparing the instant pudding as per package directions and mixing the two types of completed pudding would likely work.